# CloudKit is limiting the number of push notifications from a CKQuerySubscription

Tags: apple-push-notifications, push, cloudkit, ckquerysubscription

CloudKit is sending only 50-100 push notifications as a result of a CKQuerySubscription firing.  For one subscription the limit seems to be 56.  I can see the pushes on the Dashboard.  I can see my user ID on that list of pushes.  During the day it has moved lower and lower on that list of 56.  Then it hit the bottom and fell off - I no longer get the push notifications.  And the pushes go out at only about 10/second.  How do I increase the number of push notifications that can be sent and increase the speed at which they are sent?

Comment: This is not really but I've ran into similar issues in the past. (e.g. see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/112263). I think you best bet is to contact DTS at apple and see if they tell you why you are being rate limited.

Comment: I am not only being 'rate limited' I am being number limited - 50-100, no more.  I see the only responses you got on the developer forum were from me.  You can see the APNs go out using the Dashboard Log.  have you seen more than 100?  DTS told me to file a Bug Report.  That sat for 3 weeks until I emailed everybody I knew and asked for help.  Now they are investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I interacted with DTS and various other contacts within Apple.  DTS had me submit a Bug Report but no response.  Finally someone from DTS got the "CloudKit team" to do something that increased the capacity of the push notifications that CloudKit sends out when a subscription fires.  It now sends out over 2000 pushes.  I do not know if that is the correct number but no users are complaining about not getting alerts.